# Ejabberd: mod_roster_odbc not starting‏

Tags: ejabberd

After enabling mod_roster_odbc module, when I try to restart my server I see the below in my log.

```
2015-02-26 14:07:03.725 [critical] <0.836.0>@gen_mod:start_module:94 Problem     starting the module mod_roster_odbc for host <<"localhost">>
 options: []
 error: undef
[{mod_roster_odbc,start,[<<"localhost">>,[]],[]},
 {gen_mod,start_module,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,83}]},
 {lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1336}]},
 {ejabberd_app,start,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,69}]},
 {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                     [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,272}]}]
2015-02-26 14:07:03.726 [critical] <0.836.0>@gen_mod:start_module:99     ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
The trace is [{mod_roster_odbc,start,[<<"localhost">>,[]],[]},    {gen_mod,start_module,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,83}]},{lists,foreach,2,    [{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1336}]},{ejabberd_app,start,2,    [{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,69}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,    [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,272}]}].
(END)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: This seems to be out of topic as this does not seem to be a programming question, but more a configuration / installation on ejabberd.

Comment: well I posted the same question to http://serverfault.com/ but didnt get any response from there. Sorry about that ....

Comment: No problem, as explained this is an installation problem: missing modules or version mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  a problem with your install. Error mean that some modules / functions are not found.